# I have a problem writing the code for a C++ program for natural numbers

Tags: c++

I have some difficulties making the code for my homework assignment.
The program should contain at least 2 functions and should do this:

- reads a natural number n
- and prints out the sum: 1 + 2.3 + 3.4.5 + 4.5.6.7 +...+ n.(n + 1)...(2n - 1). 
  Thanks!

Comment: Does the `'.'` respresent multiplication or is it a separator?  Common symbol for multiplication is `'*'`.  In U.S. terms, `2.3` is a decimal quantity, 2 and 3/10.

Comment: Write one function that produces one of the products, one that produces the sum of them.

Comment: @LuboslavBlagoev What specific problem have you encountered whilst trying to complete the task?

Comment: '.' is just for the output.I mean it should be like 1+2.3+3.4.5+....+ n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1). I just have no idea how to write the function that sums the numbers.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While it is OK to ask for homework help on SO, you should at least take some effort to solve the problem yourself, otherwise you don't learn anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. What you need to do is to try writing the code yourself and, when you get stuck, post a question here showing what you have done and explaining where you are stuck. You will find that once you do that, people here will be very helpful. But not until ...

Comment: @AdrianW thanks for the advice. I will countinue trying and if a get stuck i shall ask for help

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you have to print out a sequence of numbers respect the expression:

```
a=1 a=2   a=3     a=4  ... for(a=1; a<=n; a++)
|   |     |       |
1; 2,3; 3,4,5; 4,5,6,7; ... ; while b < (2n - 1)
|  | |  |
b=1| b=3|   ... for(b=a; b<=(2*a)-1; b++)
   b=2  b=3
```

.

```
int n;
int sum; // ? It's no clear what you should sum

std::cout<<"choose n:"<<std::endl;
std::cin>>n;
std::cout<<"you have chosen: "<<n<<std::endl;

for(int a=1; a<=n; a++){
    for(int b=a; b<=(2*a)-1; b++){
        std::cout<<b<<".";
    } 
    std::cout<<" + ";
}
```

Comment: please don't spoon fed the code to a "pls gimme the code" question. Especially without any explanation whatsoever. It's not helping anyone, least of all the OP

Comment: @bolov Thanks for pointing it out, I was just editing the answer.

Comment: " '.' is just for the output.I mean it should be like 1+2.3+3.4.5+....+ n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1) " He said.